# Problems when using setTimeout in setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want to use `setTimeout` in `setInterval`. First time it print `out_k:0`. After the interval, it prints `out_k:1`, `inside_k:0`? I don't understand, I think the `inside_k` should be **1**. The `ouside k` was **1**, its so strange.

```
     var i = 0;
     var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(i < arr.length){
            var k=i;
            //console.log("out_i:"+i);
            console.log("out_k:"+k);                
            setTimeout(function(){
                //console.log("inside_i:"+i);
                console.log("inside_k:"+k);
            },500);
            i++;
        }else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }   
    },500);
```

Comment: what is `arr.length`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the sequence of events during the execution of your code

1) It queued up the first instance of `setInterval` to be executed after 500ms

2) After 500ms, it queues up **second** instance of `setInterval` and executes **first** instance of `setInterval` and prints `out_k0`. It also queues up `setTimeout` to be executed after 500ms as well when the value of `k` was still `0`.

3) After 500ms, it queues up third instance of `setInterval` and executes second instance of `setInterval` and prints `out_k1` since value of k is 1 now, but first instance of `setTimeout` is also executed with `inside_k0`

and so on.

Comment: You mean setTimeout got the value of k when it queues up?But  if I change k to i,it got the the value of i when executed .